# batch file to tshark

Tags: batch-file, tshark

In `tshark` I use the following command to prevent problems caused by using `tshark` live capture for long time

```
tshark -i 3 -b duration:60 -b files:5
```

This command will create only five `pcap` files any new file will replace old one so I want to create batch file or program that convert any new `pcap` file generated by `tshark` to `csv` file with specific fields

```
-T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data.text -e  tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack -e tcp.analysis.out_of_order -e tcp.analysis.retransmission -e tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.spurious_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.zero_window -e tcp.stream -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e data.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d
```

how can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: A snippet of your `pcap` file....

Comment: can you be more specific @SachaDee

Comment: An example of a `pcap` file to generate a `csv`.